# AngularJS 101: ng-init with ng-repeat - what am I missing in this example?

Tags: angularjs

```
Below snippet doesn't run. 
What am I missing here with ng-init?!! 
If I change array values to 'non-repeating' values it works.
For example, changing 
names=['Jani','Hege','Kavi','Kavi2'] 
it works.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kavi','Kavi']">
  <p>Looping with ng-repeat:</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
      {{ x }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This `track by $index`: you can check documentation - [Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<li ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
      {{ x }}
 </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer..  From the documentation -"The default tracking function (which tracks items by their identity) does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.

If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression."